# 2 локальные сети (2 TP_LINK) на 1 внешнем статическом IP

Tags: ip, lan, маршрутизатор

Добрый день! У меня стоит задача в организации передачи пакетов по протоколам TCP/UDP посредством проброса портов на конкретные локальные ip, которые поступают на внешний ip. Имею на руках 2 TP-Link TL-R480+. Один роутер может пробросить максимально 16 портов. Мне нужно больше. Так уж, получается, что роутеры при одновременной работе с одним IP внешним конфликтуют, конечно же. Каким образом, используя данные железяки, могу получить 2 разные Сети внутренние с одним внешним IP, чтобы я мог дополнительно пробрасывать порты в одной или другой внутренней Сети?

Comment: Диапазон портов считается одним портом в настройках?

Answer (score 0):

На TP-Link TL-R480+ в настройках в качестве порта трансляции можно указать слитный диапазон портов. См. [эмулятор](https://www.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/TL-R480T+_UN_9.0_Emulator/index.html), Transmission - NAT - Virtual Servers. Соответственно если диапазон пробрасываемых портов имеет слитный блок из 16 (или менее) портов, можно первым роутером пробросить его на второй, а там уже раздать клиентам по одному. И остальные 15 портов на первом роутере также раздать отдельным клиентам.

Правда, при этом надо понимать, что часть клиентов сети относительно другой части будет за NAT, так что клиенты за первым роутером не смогут получать доступ к клиентам за вторым роутером.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Подскажите, как тогда формировать подсеть? если первый роутер имеет свой IP 11.2.0.1, какой IP следует присвоить второму роутеру, и какие внутренние IP следует статические для маршрутизации портов использовать на ПК в подсети от второго роутера?

Comment: Кроме того, нужные мне порты на IP второго роутера можно указать в диапазоне, и одно правило на IP. Но возникает тогда другая проблема, есть порты, которые попадают в диапазон других правил маршрутизации...

Comment: *если первый роутер имеет свой IP 11.2.0.1, какой IP следует присвоить второму роутеру* Серый. Он же приватный. RFC1918 в помощь. *какие внутренние IP* То же самое. Но не пересекаться по подсетям. *есть порты, которые попадают в диапазон других правил маршрутизации* Принимайте меры, чтобы пересечений не было.